# Match all hrefs, except the .js or .css hrefs

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match all the links on a page, but I don't want to capture the css or js files

the best I can come up with is this

```
^href=".*[^\.css | ^\.js]"$
```

but it matches some weird text as well, like this one:

```
href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet"
```

any ideas? I've been trying and googling an anwser for my problem, but nothing so far

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use negative lookahead:

```
href="[^.]+(?!(?:css|js)).*"
```

But rather than regex there might be better ways of scrapping a HTML page like DOM parser.

Comment: It would be better but in my case it has to be regex, I'm using an application that only uses regex :\

Comment: Yes I have provided you a regex solution :P

Comment: you're too kind sir :) , but actually it still matches the same string :\ for which language is that regex?

Comment: You didn't specify any language. My regex should work for JS, PHP etc.

Comment: hmm, indeed it should work with JS, it's just I saw you using the character ':' and I don't know what that's supposed to do

(I'm using this to guide me http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)

Comment: I'm using a regex for groovy (I'm new to the job had to ask around!)

Comment: If it doesn't work for you you should create a sample regex code on rubular.com OR regexpal.com and provide me link so that I can fix the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet"
```

doesn't have .css in it, but only css (without dot). Isn't that why it's finding it?

Comment: yes, I didn't want to match that one either. I need to match string that contains 'css' or 'js' (probably better .js)